# reading and modifying inline style "height" using jquery?

Tags: jquery

In page I have below tag:

```
<div id="main_body" class="mainbox" style="height: 769px;">
```

I can select this div using:

```
   var diiv= $("#main_body")
```

Can you please guide me how to read and modify the hight attribute in, inline style. I need to read this for some other calculation as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var diiv= $("#main_body");
var height = diiv.css('height')//read
divv.css('height', 800)//set
```

Answer (score 3):

Read:

```
var element = $("#main_body");
var currentHeight = element.height();
```

Set:

```
var newHeight = 100;//define the new height here
element.height(newHeight);
```

The above will let you read and set the height

Answer (score 2):

`$('#main_body').css('height')`

This will retrieve the height.

`$('#main_body').css('height', 150)`

This will set the height.