# How to obtain the height of a collection of classes from the style property

Tags: jquery, css

I need to obtain the current height in the "style" section of 813px in Jquery.

Example of F12 CSS -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wFfR.jpg

I've tried to do this:

```
function HandleAccordionControlSizeChanges(isOpened) {
    var currentHeight = 0;

    if (isOpened) {
        currentHeight = $(".dx-accordion-item-opened").height();
    }
    else {
        currentHeight = $(".dx-accordion-item-closed").height();
    }

    return currentHeight;
}
```

So I need to pull out the style tag that has 813px.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626784/reading-and-modifying-inline-style-height-using-jquery "Use .css()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the height is set in the CSS, you can use [`.css('height')`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) if you want the `px` appended, and [`.height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) if you want the raw integer value:

```js
console.log($('.element').css('height'));
console.log($('.element').height());
```

```css
.element {
  height: 813px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">Example</div>
```

However, note that both of these only work on the **computed** (existing) value. If you set the `height` in CSS, then these methods will pick the `height` up - if you set it in JavaScript, they won't.

For **inline** styles you'll want to use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jQuery, or alternatively target the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) itself (with `[0]`), and use the raw [`.style.height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

```js
console.log($('.element').attr('style'));
console.log($('.element')[0].style.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element" style="height: 813px;">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer: [reading and modifying inline style "height" using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626784/reading-and-modifying-inline-style-height-using-jquery)

> Use .css()

But jquery oficial doc indicates to use ".height()" to use with math operations:

https://api.jquery.com/height/

> The difference between .css( "height" ) and .height() is that the
>   latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the
>   former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The
>   .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be
>   used in a mathematical calculation.